# Wait for async Task method in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have spent hours - if not days - on the following seemingly simple issue.

I am working on a Xamarin-app that consumes data from a backend by calling a webservice. It also stores these data in an internal SQLite-Database once it is downloaded, to avoid unneccessary webservice calls. Data downloaded once on the first app start and then only updated, if the data in the backend has been updated.

Let's say I have a repository which will load data either (asynchronously) from the backend by calling the webservice or (synchronously) from an internal SQLite-Database. The repository is responsible for delivering the data, regardless of it's origin. The repository stores object references of the data in an internal list which can publicly be accessed. The repository is a generic abstract class which is only subclassed by the implementing classes to provide information about the Type. All the logic to synchronize with the backend is encapsulated in the repository (as far as my understanding goes this is the Repository-Pattern)

After the repository  gets constructed it is loaded by calling the Load()-method. This method is async, because it does the following things:

- Get the Date of the last modification in the backend. This is done only once the app started. The last modification date is stored as a property.
- Store object references of the data by calling a `GetAll()`-method. This method is marked as async and can be of asynchronous or synchronous nature, depending on where the data is loaded from (see code below)

  - If the data is outdated, the most current data is downloaded first by calling the webservice. The downloaded data is then stored in the internal SQLite-Database, replacing all previously downloaded data.
  - After (if at all) the data has been downloaded, the `GetAll()`-method returns the data by querying the SQLite-database. This is the synchronous call provided by the SQLite.NET-Package.

What does not work (and what I don't understand) is the following behavior:

- When the repository is loaded for the first time (i.e. `NeedsUpdate` returns `true`, everything works fine. So far so good.
- On all subsequent calls (=app starts) loading the repository results in a `System.NullReferenceException` exception. Debugging the code has shown that the `Refresh()`-Method is indeed not called from `GetAll()` (=expected behavior).

I know that you should not use async void Methods and that methods marked as async should always return a Task. Apparently, the latter is not the case in my code. So how can I make this work?

Here's my code:

### BasViewModel.cs (calls Load() on Repository)

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : MvxViewModel
{
    protected IRepository<T> Repository;

    public virtual async Task Init()
    {
        if (Repository != null)
        {
            await Repository.Load();                
        }                
    }
}
```

### Repository.cs

```
 public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>

    protected List<T> ItemList = new List<T>();
    public List<T> Items
    {
        get { return ItemList; }
        set
        {                
            ItemList = value;
            if (ItemsChanged != null)
                ItemsChanged(this, ItemList);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task Load()
    {
        if (CurrentUpdate.Equals(DateTime.MaxValue) || CurrentUpdate.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
            CurrentUpdate = await WebService.Status(exception => { });
        Items = await GetAll();
    }

    public virtual async Task<List<T>> GetAll()
    {
        if (NeedsUpdate)
            await Refresh();

        return DbService.All();
    }

    public async Task Refresh()
    {
        var result = await WebService.DoGet(error => { });
        if (ItemsDownloaded != null)
            ItemsDownloaded(this, result);
        ReloadDatabase(result);
    }

    protected void ReloadDatabase(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        DbService.DeleteAll();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            DbService.Insert(item);
        }
        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        FileService.WriteFile(FileName, LastUpdate.ToString());
    }
}
```

### DatabaseService.cs

```
public abstract class DatabaseService<T> {
    public List<T> All()
    {
        // ISQLiteConnection was instantiated before
        return Connection.Table<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

### WebService.cs

```
public abstract class WebService<T>
    public virtual async Task<List<T>> DoGet(Action<Exception> error)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com/myApi");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
        }
    }
 }
```

### Stacktrace

```
06-17 14:21:43.701 D/AndroidRuntime( 2897): Shutting down VM
The thread 'Unknown' (0x4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
An unhandled exception occured.

06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): Process: ch.bbv.fumetto, PID:     2897
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): java.lang.RuntimeException:     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     ... 1 more
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable:     System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0003b>
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:18
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d419c934/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:71
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.5b2f2ea1-978e-4306-9701-97a7ac2d86c0 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0001f>
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897): 
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-17 14:21:45.760 E/AndroidRuntime( 2897):     ... 4 more
06-17 14:21:49.772 I/Process ( 2897): Sending signal. PID: 2897 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where does the exception occur? What is its callstack?

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: Where's the code `await`ing the `Load` method?

Comment: I added the Stacktrace and the code calling/awaiting `Load` on the Repository